# Laravel: Querying and accessing child objects in nested relationship with where clauses Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I have a problem to make my laravel query

Model Regions

```
class Region extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'regions';

    protected $guarded = [

    ];

    public function county()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\County');
    }


    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\CompanyInfo', 
        'region_company','region_id','company_id');
    }
```

Model Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $guarded = [];


    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Company', 'categories_company','category_id','company_id');
    }
}
```

Model Company

```
class Company extends Model
{

    protected $table ='companies';

    protected $guarded = [

    ];

    public function regions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Region', 'region_company','company_id','region_id');
    }

}
```

I have a input form where I want to filter by  category and region and the output should be categories with companies if possible but I want to show only 10 companies per category. Not sure it is is possible.

here is what I have till now

```
$categories = $request->input('categories');

    $region = $request->input('regions');

    $companies = Category::whereIn('id',$categories)->with([
        'companies.regions' => function ($query) use ($region) {
            $query->whereIn('id', $region);
        }])->get();
```

the problem here is that it is filtering the categories but it is still giving me all companies not filtering out the once that belong to certain region.

thank you 
Dany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$categories = $request->input('categories');
$region = $request->input('regions');

$companies = Category::whereIn('id',$categories)->with([
    'companies' => function ($query) use ($region) {
        $query->whereHas('region', function ($q2) use ($region){
            $q2->whereIn('id', $region);
        });
        $query->with(['region']);
        $query->limit(10);
    }])->whereHas('companies', function($q) use ($region) {
        $q->whereHas('region', function ($q2) use ($region){
            $q2->whereIn('id', $region);
        });
    })->get();
```

Comment: Hi @clod986 thank you for quick reply but I am getting a error syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) it seems that after    $q2->whereIn('id', $region);
        } it is missing something I tried ; and , but still the same issue

Comment: @user1859876 should be working now, I forgot to close the statements

Comment: @user1859876 if it gives you an "undefined index ID" error, replace ID with REGION_ID or REGIONS.ID

Comment: I just realized one more point that the limit(10) shows me only 10 results but for all categories not per category. It should show max 10 companies per category can you help?

Comment: @user1859876 I think the best option is to do it directly from the model. Check this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-51-eloquent-relationship-hasmany-limit-records